# How to update values in arrays of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change values of array of objects. The keys 1,2 are dynamic and come from json.

```
var rows = [
  {
    "1": "14",
    "2": "55",
    "named": "name1",
    "row": 7
  },
  {
    "1": "15",
    "2": "56",
    "named": "nameper",
    "row": 9
  },
  ...
]
```

to. The name having nameper should have per cent values.

```
[
    {
      "1": "14",
      "2": "55",
      "named": "name1",
      "row": 7
    },
    {
      "1": "15%",
      "2": "56%",
      "named": "nameper",
      "row": 9
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows.map((singleItem) => {
   if(singleItem.named === "nameper"){
      singleItem["1"] = singleItem["1"] + "%";
      singleItem["2"] = singleItem["2"] + "%";
   }
})
```

Comment: Arun V was a little faster than you, making your answer a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` or `map` or a for-loop

Using `forEach`.

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
    if (row["named"] === "nameper") {
        row["1"] = row["2"] + "%";
        row["2"] = row["2"] + "%";
    }
})
```

You can use `map` in a similar way!

Using `for` loop

```
for (var row of rows) {
    if (row["named"] === "nameper") {
        row["1"] = row["2"] + "%";
        row["2"] = row["2"] + "%";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows.map(row => {
    if(row["named"] === "nameper") {
          row["1"] = `${row["1"]}%`
          row["2"] = `${row["2"]}%`
    }
})
```

you can use a map and check for the named and update it accordingly